# using a proper parameter in uploading data to MsSQL using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I am having a trouble using a parameters, I want to insert the uploaded file into the MsSQL database from the file upload in my webpage. I am using codeigniter as my framework.

**Controller**

```
function upload_gen048()
{

$data['filedate']=$this->input->post('fiil');
//print_r ($data);

$this->load->model('navi_model');
$query = $this->navi_model->upload_gen048($data);
```

**Model**
    function upload_gen048($data)
    {

```
$x = explode('.',$data['filedate']);

//print_r ($data);

$qString = "";
$qString .= '[dbo].[gen048upload] '; //STORED PROCEDURE
$qString .= "'" .$data['fiil']."','" .$data['filedate']."'";
echo $qString;
```

**View**

```
<form  id="upload" name="upload" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/upload_gen048" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return verify_upload()" >

<input style="border:1px solid" type="text" onfocus="true"  name="fiil" id="fiil" value=""size="30" />

<input type="file" name="uploadData" id="uploadData" onChange="fileSelect();" style=""/>
```

here is my Stored Procedure, it is all working when I execute it independently but I cant insert data from my webpage.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gen048upload]
(
        @fileDate VARCHAR(20)

)

AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @sql varchar(8000),@sourceTable varchar(500), @dynamic varchar(8000), @tablesuffix varchar(10)
select @tablesuffix=upper(substring(datename(m,convert(datetime,@fileDate)),1,3))+convert(varchar,year(convert(datetime,@fileDate)))
print @tablesuffix


create table #logs(
i int identity(1,1),
tableName varchar(50),
status varchar(30)
)

set @sourceTable ='gen_048_'+@tablesuffix
insert into #logs(tableName,status) select @sourceTable,'CREATED'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = @sourceTable)
BEGIN
    set @sql = '
    CREATE TABLE '+@sourceTable+'
    (
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Message: Undefined index: fiil
Filename: models/navi_model.php
Line Number: 57
both sides are working, my web page and my MsSQL stored precedure but I think my problem here is I cant connect them to each other because of my parameters in my model.

Comment: I can't see where you're filling in the `$data` hash. You only set the `filedate` index on it, and not the `fiil` index which the error mentions. You should check that `$data` contains what you are expecting before you start indexing into it.

Comment: Yes, I know but I can't code it properly. I can think of the way to do it but I cant actually do it by coding it. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
function upload_gen048()
{
    // Here you make a array, with a key 'filedate'
    $data['filedate']=$this->input->post('fiil');
    //print_r ($data);

    $this->load->model('navi_model');
    $query = $this->navi_model->upload_gen048($data);

 function upload_gen048($data) {
     $x = explode('.',$data['filedate']);
     //print_r ($data);
    $qString = "";
    $qString .= '[dbo].[gen048upload] '; //STORED PROCEDURE

// Here you try to get array key 'fiil', but you haven't set that in your code.
    $qString .= "'" .$data['fiil']."','" .$data['filedate']."'";
    echo $qString;
```

Remove $data['fiil'] and your code should work.
Also var_dump($data); to see exactly what is in your array, you would have seen that $data['fiil'] does not exist.